# Sorting an array by a record alphabetically?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I want to sort an array in my maths quiz to have it so it sorts the names from A-Z but I have done a lot of research and cannot find a way to do this. Other people who are doing the same task are using around one or two lines at the end of there bit of code.

Don't get angry at me this is my first question and I am not the best at this as I have left it for a long while to do other coursework and tasks.

Example of the layout of my code:

```
#Highest to Lowest
if format_choice == "A":
        scores = {}
        with open("classA.txt","r") as result_f:
            for line in result_f:
                (name, secondname, score) = line.split()
                scores[score] = name
        result_f.close()
```

This works by taking the highest score in the file and printing it into the shell.

If this is not enough information I can show more if people want to see more.

Thank you.

Comment: How is it the highest?

Comment: Pretty sure you should just dump the whole program on here so we can actually debug it. You describe printing that's going on but there's no printing to be found.

Comment: Are you trying to print a list of `name`s and `score`s alphabetically sorted?

Comment: `print sorted(scores.values())`

Comment: Your question title says sorting an array, but you are storing your name data in a dictionary.

Comment: I cannot fit the whole file onto a comment? Is there a way to message you the code?

Comment: @L.Freeston: yes, edit the question. Also, don't paste whole file -- short sample should do.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hasty lot of code, but this should work:

```
#Highest to Lowest
if format_choice == "A":
    with open("classA.txt","r") as result_f:
        scores = []
        for line in result_f:
            [name, secondname, score] = line.split()
            record = [name, secondname, score] # We make a list called "record" With name as its first record
            scores.append(record) # We stick that list onto scores each time
        scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda File: File[0])
    # This is difficult to describe, but this sorts all the lists by their first record, File[0] or names,
    result_f.close()

    print(scores)
    # This prints [['eric', 'ericlastname', '98'], ['fred', 'fredlastname', '2'], ['steve', 'stevelastname', '1']]
```

In the text file, it was this:

steve stevelastname 1
fred fredlastname 2
eric ericlastname 98

I also changed your `scores = {}` into `scores = []` as you wanted an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Close the question, if you accept my answer, then this won't come up as unanswered when people search it,